# k8s ClusterIP:Port accessible only within the node of running the pod

Tags: kubernetes

I create 3 ubuntu VMs in AWS and use kubeadm to set up the cluster in the master nodes and open port 6443. and apply flannel network via below command:

```
 kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

And the I join the other two nodes to the cluster via command join:

```
kubeadm join 172.31.5.223:6443
```

The I apply below two yaml to deploy my deployment and svc
[image]
[image]

Here comes the issue. I output all resources in k8s master:
[image]

1. I can only access clusterip:port inside the node/ip-172-31-36-90 as it has pod running.
   Which results:
   I can only access /:NodePorts using IP of node/ip-172-31-36-90 as it has pod running.

I can use curl <externalip/internal of the node/ip-172-31-36-90>:nodeport in other nodes. But this IP can only be ip-172-31-36-90.

If I try above two using IP of master node or node/ip-172-31-41-66, it will get a timeout issue. Notice: Nodeport 30000 are open on all nodes via aws security group.

Anyone can help me with this network issue? I am really bad at debug network stuff.

2.Second question, If I try curl <externalip/internal of the node/ip-172-31-36-90>:nodeport in my local machine, it gives error :
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

It really bothers me. k8s expert please save me!!!

----------------Update---------------------------

After days of debugging, I notice it is related to IPs of docker0 and flannel.1
, they are not in the same subnet:
[image]

But I still don't where I have I done wrong and how to sync them. Any export here, please!

Comment: Check if all the required ports (eg. 5000, 30000) are opened in the security group that attached to your worker nodes.

Comment: TO debug, I open all ports... but not working

Comment: I replicate the scenario in Oracle cloud and use weave as the network addon. Issue solved. Not sure whether it is cloud provider issue or network addon issue.